# Prove that operator is Bounded below operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $A:X\rightarrow Y$, Where $X,Y$ are Hilbert Spaces, be bounded linear operator. Then show that, for every $\alpha \gt 0$, $A^*A+\alpha I$ is bounded below. Where $A^*=$ Adjoint of $A$.

Attempt: An operator$A$ is called bounded below if there exist $c\gt 0$ such that 
$$||Ax||\ge c||x||, \forall x\in X$$

$||(A^*A+\alpha I)x||=||A^*Ax+\alpha x||\le(||A^*A||+\alpha)||x||$ I'm stuck here. Help is needed. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Evaluate
$$(x, (A^*A+\alpha\,I) \, x)_X$$
and draw the right consequences.

Comment: $(x, (A^*A+\alpha\,I) \, x)=(x,A^*Ax)+(x,\alpha\,x)=||Ax||^2+\alpha ||x||^2\le (||A||^2+\alpha )||x||^2$ what after this?

Comment: No, you have to use $\|A \, x\| \ge 0$.

Comment: you mean to say I should go as Fred already did? can't i get the result by proceeding in my way?

Comment: Yes, my hint points in the same direction as Fred's answer, but you do not need to write down the inverse. And no, by your way you only get an upper bound, but you want to have a lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

From $(A^*Ax,x)=(Ax,Ax)=||Ax||^2 \ge 0$, we see that the spectrum of the selfadjoint operator $A^*A$ is contained in $[0, \infty)$. Hence $A^*A+\alpha I$ is invertible ( $ \alpha >0$).

Let $B$ be the inverse of $A^*A+\alpha I$. Then for each $x \in X$ we have

$$||x||=||B(A^*A+\alpha I)x|| \le ||B||*|| (A^*A+\alpha I)x||.$$